# Excel - Circular References (all values change when one changes)

Tags: forms, reference, circular-reference

I have several products. Each product has four different dimensions, and they're each dependent on one another. Meaning, if I know one, I know the rest of them.

Each product is different, so the way that they depend on each other is different. But the fact of the matter doesn't change-if i know one value of any dimension - i know the rest.

I'd like to be able to just type in a value into the cell and have excel automatically populate the rest for me.

It's too tedious with VBA and i'd like it to be automatic upon entry, and not have to have someone click a button. Just when you type it in.

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide some more details?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/1zqsmlg/8

Comment: i want to be able to click again to any of those filled in cells and it will automatically update it based on what i just typed in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is impossible without VBA. I offer you a simple method instead:

There's an infinite amount of ways to do that. I want some SE points. So, I will just post the first method that comes to mind.

Have two rows:
Input: [Height] [Width] [Length] 
Result: [Height] [Width] [Length]

(the above will have the following shape:) 
A1 B1 C1 D1 
A2 B2 C2 D2

You don't touch the result row. You input into the blank input rows and then the result rows check for the input and calculate accordingly. 
In the result row, you will use "nested if", NOT(ISBLANK(A1)) and your own calculation method. Here's an example of nested if: 
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A1)),A1*2,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B1)),B1*3,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(C1)),C1*4, IF(NOT(ISBLANK(D1)),D1*5))))

Each cell in the result row will require a different calculation formula. 
I suggest you open a brand new excel worksheet and paste the above formula into cell A2. Then, type a number into either A1, B1, C1 or D1 and notice what happens in cell A2.
Also, please note the above formula has not been "fixed". If you drag the formula, excel will try to adjust it and things can go bad.

Comment: Looks like I will use VBA. Thank you